# Where file revisions are stored on OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystem, file-sharing, file, versions

Most Apple applications in newer OS X versions, like OS X 10.9, automatically save all changes to all files and documents without your approval, and file versions and revisions are automatically available from within a submenu within the File menu.

Where are such revisions saved, filesystem-wise?

If one is to exchange such files, how would one ensure that none of the history gets exchanged, too?

What if one did want to exchange the history, is there a way to accomplish that as well?

Answer (score 3):

The different versions of the file are stored in a hidden folder named `.DocumentRevisions-V100` in the root of the volume. On recent macOS versions, such as Big Sur and Monterey, you'll find it in the root of the Data volume:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/.DocumentRevisions-V100
```

When you exchange files by copying them, sending them as attachments through email, AirDropping them, uploading them to a web site, copying to a cloud drive or similar - it is only the actual file itself that is exchanged. That is, it is the most recent version that you're exchanging. So there's really nothing to worry about there - it happens automatically.

If you actually want to exchange the history with the file, I'm afraid that's not immediately possible - there's no user interface for copying the files with past versions. You can of course manually open up each past version and save them as separate files.

Comment: Same location in Catalina

Answer (score 0):

Versions are stored within the same file so a myfile.pages will have all there versions stored within it.

A version is only stored when you save from the file menu or use <kbd>cmd</kbd>- <kbd>S</kbd>

The version is just a bit of text that details the changes made since the last version so is not a copy of the file at that stage.

So if you sent the file to someone else they should get all the previous versions as well.

Comment: What about the files like the `.png` images?  Clearly a version is stored not only when `⌘S` is used.

Comment: Preview doesn't make versions for pictures. The file type of png does not work with versioning on OSX natively. Any pngs within a pages doc for example will be contained within the pages package. (A pages a "file" is in fact a directory of smaller files that are built into the document when opened). Only certain document types are version able.

Comment: But I do have different versions of a `.png` file in Preview -- it offers the option of getting back to an older version, all through the File menu on OS X 10.9.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as the versions are definitely not stored within the file itself.